How to filter out logs spit out from daemons?
I have a program that produces some erroneous logs that I don't to see for now. Therefore I write the below function to filter out those lines before writing to syslog using busybox syslogd
function filter_and_log() {
    # Temporarily disable these logs for now because they're very noisy
    grep -vF -e 'missing device' -e '[error] log' | logger -p local0.info -t "$1"
}

And run it like this from a root account
${DAEMON_NAME} 2>&1 | filter_and_log ${DAEMON_NAME} &

But in the syslog file there are still lots of missing device and [error] log lines that I've removed. It's even weirder because if I echo some string | filter_and_log test then they work correctly and I can see the lines printed or not in syslog as expected
Why is that? How can I fix it?

Perhaps the program is also calling syslog() (see man 3 syslog) to log messages. busybox syslog.conf only allows for filtering on facility (kern user mail daemon auth syslog lpr news uucp cron authpriv ftp) and priority. You might want to change to rsyslogd which is more sophisticated, but also much bigger.
